# What is the correct field it should be applied

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I cannot figure out what kind of field shoud I use in my serializer class if in the model it is a ForeignKey

```
    class DotPrivateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

        tag = serializers.________________Field(
            queryset=TagPrivate.objects.filter(user=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
        )
```

models.py

```
    class DotPrivate(models.Model):

        user = models.ForeignKey(
            settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
            on_delete=models.CASCADE       
        )
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        description = models.TextField(max_length=350, blank=True)
        lon = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        lat = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        rating = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0), MaxValueValidator(5.0)])
        tag = models.ForeignKey('TagPrivate', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield). The below code will nest the Foreign Key record in the json.

```
class DotPrivateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    tag = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    def get_tag(self,obj):        
        queryset=TagPrivate.objects.filter(user=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
        return TagPrivateSerializer(queryset).data
```